# Reading a value of css styles using nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, nodes

i wan to create new css with lowest and highest value.

```
     table[my-type="myStyle"] {
        width: 255.388px !important;
    }
```

and the above code present in n number of css files in my style directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) to parse the css and get the values you want.

Here is an example of how to get min and max width from different css files (for the same selector `table[my-type="myStyle"]`):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const postcss = require('postcss');

const allWidthValues = [];

const files = [
    'styles/style-1.css',
    'styles/style-2.css',
    'styles/style-3.css'
];

const selector = 'table[my-type="myStyle"]';

const processor = postcss.plugin('processor', () => (css) => {    
    // Callback for each rule node.
    css.walkRules((rule) => {        
        // Match the individual rule selector 
        if (rule.selector.indexOf(selector) !== -1) {
            // Callback for each declaration.
            rule.walkDecls(decl => {
                // Find the width declaration
                if(decl.prop.indexOf('width') !== -1) {
                    const width = decl.value.replace('px', '') * 1;
                    allWidthValues.push(width);
                }
            })
        }
    });
});

files.forEach(file => {
    const css = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8');
    postcss([processor])
        .process(css, {from : file})
        .then(() => console.log('Done processing file : ', file))
        .catch(() => console.log('Error processing file : ', file));    

});

console.log('All width values : ', allWidthValues);

allWidthValues.sort();

console.log('Min width : ', allWidthValues[0]);
console.log('Max width : ', allWidthValues[allWidthValues.length - 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks MohamedRamrami, Is there any way to avoid this,         `const files = [
    'styles/style-1.css',
    'styles/style-2.css',
    'styles/style-3.css'
];` ie, can we get the files list from style directory by automated ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the npm package `glob`, like this `const files = glob.sync('./styles/*.css');`

Comment: That will return all css files in the styles directory